# Integrating jQuery autocomplete with Google site search

Tags: database, jquery-ui, search, autocomplete, web

I have a bit of an odd situation. I have to implement search on a public facing website  -but, that search must be able to search both web pages and have an autocomplete/suggestion functionality that comes from a list of terms that are in a DB table.

So, I'm wondering a couple things: 1) should I be looking at Google search and jQuery autocomplete? 2) is there something else I should be looking at instead? 3) if this is the right path to be heading down are the enough pointers on implementation?

The crux of my problem is that the terms that I need to use for the autocomplete/suggest functionality reside within a database and not on the webpages. So, I thought Google would be appropriate for search the webpages and that I could sort of fill in the blanks so to speak with these terms from the DB. I'm going to say that there are roughly 20-40,000 terms or so that need autocomplete. But that is really just a very rough guess -it could be less.

I'm open to ideas and not really married to any particular solution. However, I will admit to liking the ideas of offloading the search to Google. I hear they have a good algorithm ;)

Any ideas, thoughts, or leads are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question: Apache Solr seems to be the way to go. Powerful, configurable, free, and fast. It powers sites like Netflix. Version 4.0 beta is currently out and seems stable.